# Transaction hash generation in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When a call is made from Hyperledger Composer to Fabric runtime, is the transaction hash generated only after the commit in the entire network. If thats the case, should we wait synchronously and track the data from traditional system. Like in ethereum cant we get a transaction hash immediately and track the commit status later.What is the best way of handling this in Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like in ethereum we can get transaction hash inside the smart-contract/chaincode in HL fabric too, it doesn't matter if later transaction is committed or not.

For every invocation request, a transaction ID is generated, it can be accessed by a method

> getTxId()

(in java chaincode, similarly can be found in go/node cc) which returns a String transaction id for that request.

refer  [Java chaincode getTxId](https://fabric-chaincode-java.github.io/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeStub.html#getTxId--)

Comment: Thanks Harshit, composer is combining the proposal and respond only when the transaction is committed. This must be from fabric sdk.

Comment: well i have not worked with composer, but i can tell you that even if a transaction is committed or not in world state a transaction hash is generated